# Would it be possible for me to connect to the RocketChat application that is on the official IOS site with RocketChat sever that I have made?

Tags: gitlab, rocket.chat

Would it be possible for me to connect to the RocketChat application that is on the official IOS site with RocketChat sever that I have made?

It seems that It can only be connected through Official SAAS by long odds.

Answer (score 2):

the current version of our Mobile app only connects to our own server. We are fixing this limitation on the next release. You can see more documentation about this at our wiki:

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/wiki/Build-the-Android-Cordova-Web-App-and-connect-to-your-own-Rocket.Chat-Server

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your own server now.

You can also connect to multiple servers at once. To do so, all you have to do is swipe up with two fingers. That will bring the servers list.

[image]